# How do I send a POST request to a PHP file?

Tags: python, php, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request in Python to a forum. I want it to update the signature from Python using requests. My code isn't working. Anyone know how to do this better, or know what I am missing?

```
import requests, json
url = "https://forum.com/usercp.php?action=editsig"

payload = {
    "my_post_key=HIDDEN&signature=%5Bfont%3DLucida+Sans+Unicode%2CLucida+Grande%2Csans-serif%5D%5Bsize%3Dx-large%5D%5Bb%5D%5Bcolor%3D%23c0392b%5Dbbbbbb+%3D%C2%A0%5B%2Fcolor%5D%5B%2Fb%5D%5B%2Fsize%5D%5B%2Ffont%5D+%3Aaaa2%3A%C2%A0MOTD%3A+TESTING%0D%0A%5Bimg%5Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ftinyimg.io%2Fi%hidden.jpeg%5B%2Fimg%5D&updateposts=enable&action=do_editsig&submit=Update+Signature"
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'forum.com'
    'Cookie': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Length': 395
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="98"'
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0'
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"'
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1
    'Origin': 'https://forum.com'
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36'
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin'
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate'
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document'
    'Referer': 'https://forum.com/usercp.php?action=editsig'
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(response.text , response.status_code)
```

The original request which is sent to the server is this, not sure how I should format it to work like this.

```
POST /usercp.php HTTP/2
Host: forum.com
Cookie: test=test
Content-Length: 395
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Sec-Ch-Ua: "(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="98"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: https://forum.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://forum.com/usercp.php?action=editsig
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

my_post_key=REMOVED&signature=%5Bfont%3DLucida+Sans+Unicode%2CLucida+Grande%2Csans-serif%5D%5Bsize%3Dx-large%5D%5Bb%5D%5Bcolor%3D%23c0392b%5Daaaaaa+%3D%C2%A0%5B%2Fcolor%5D%5B%2Fb%5D%5B%2Fsize%5D%5B%2Ffont%5D+%3Aaaa2%3A%C2%A0MOTD%3A+aaaaaa%0D%0A%5Bimg%5Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ftinyimg.io%2Fi%test.jpeg%5B%2Fimg%5D&updateposts=enable&action=do_editsig&submit=Update+Signature
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've incorrectly formatted a few things:
Firstly, the headers are meant to be a python dictionary, you need to separate each header with a comma. Also, headers are always strings so you need to change the `Content-Length` and `Upgrad-Insecure-Requests` to strings.

Lastly, your payload isn't a dictionary. You've got one long string in that "dictionary" not key-value pairs. You can send a string but you need to specify it in the request, you aren't sending JSON you are sending a string so you should format your code like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://forum.com/usercp.php?action=editsig"

payload = {
    "my_post_key=HIDDEN&signature=%5Bfont%3DLucida+Sans+Unicode%2CLucida+Grande%2Csans-serif%5D%5Bsize%3Dx-large%5D%5Bb%5D%5Bcolor%3D%23c0392b%5Dbbbbbb+%3D%C2%A0%5B%2Fcolor%5D%5B%2Fb%5D%5B%2Fsize%5D%5B%2Ffont%5D+%3Aaaa2%3A%C2%A0MOTD%3A+TESTING%0D%0A%5Bimg%5Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ftinyimg.io%2Fi%hidden.jpeg%5B%2Fimg%5D&updateposts=enable&action=do_editsig&submit=Update+Signature"
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'forum.com',
    'Cookie': 'REDACTED',
    'Content-Length': '395',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="98"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://forum.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://forum.com/usercp.php?action=editsig',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text , response.status_code)
```